# Getting an Exception while running this code

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime


while True:

    now = datetime.now().time()
    print (now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")),

    print("\r"),
    time.sleep(1)

    if now.hour == 10 and now.minute == 15 and now.second ==00:
        os.execv("/home/pi/Desktop/rasp_2016/dummy_code.py", sys.argv) 
        print ("rebooted")
        exit
```

I am trying to develop a code which restart the script a particular time. It works fine until it satisfies the if condition of given time. It throws an exception which is:

```
Exception has occurred:OSError
[Errno 8] Exec format error.
```

What could be the possible solution for that?

Comment: ```/home/pi/Desktop/rasp_2016/dummy_code.py``` isn't a binary file.  You'd have to run ```python /home/pi/Desktop/rasp_2016/dummy_code.py"```

Comment: Using ``os.execv`` *replaces* the current process. No code can run afterwards; the two trailing lines indicate your program does not do what you think it does. Is there a reason why you use ``os.execv`` instead of ``suprocess``?

Comment: Note that your system should already ship with the means to run or rerun programs at specific points in time. Look at ``cron``/``crontab`` as well as ``systemd`` ``.service`` and ``.timer`` units.